# json_encode returns only one object

Tags: php, html, json

I have this piece of code in one single file

```
//declaring something
$array=array();
$arraylst=/*retrieve from database query and sure this contains the correct result*/
<?php 
if(!empty($array)):
?>
<div id="something">
<?php
$n=0;
foreach($arraylst as $key=>$val):
    $array="span".$n;
    //create a span and print out $val's property1  
    $n++;
endforeach;

$n=0;
foreach($array as $key=>$val):
    //create a span and print out $val's property2
    $n++;
endforeach;
</div>
<?php 
endif;
?>


<script language="javascript">
var arr=[<?php echo json_encode($array); ?>]
//do something else
</script>
```

The output to the screen I see is only one "span"; that is if my `arraylst` size is 3, I can only see the first span because my database query is sorted ascendingly. The rest is not seen at all.

Answer (score 0):

`$array="span".$n;` overwrites the array with a string.

Use `array_push( $array, "span$n" );` to add an item to the array.

(Then you'll want to remove the `[` and `]` from around the `json_encode` as you'll have an array in `$array`).

Comment: THanks, I fixed that but I still get the same erroneous effect

Answer (score 0):

You always *set* the value "span" to $array.

```
$array="span".$n;
```

You do not *add* it to the array you *set* the array to that value.

Use:

```
$array[] ="span".$n;
```